# What is the true available resolution of a 10.1 Android tablet?

Tags: android, resolution

I am creating a wire-frame android application for presentational purposes only. My target device is a 1280 x 800 10.1 inch tablet. I need to know the exact resolution of the device subtracting the navigation bar at the bottom. At first I made my graphics in 1280 x 800, but they didn't fit the screen properly because of the navigation bar, does anyone know the actual available resolution for a 10.1 1280 x 800 tablet?

Comment: Are you sure that navigation bar is part of screen. I guess its not part of screen and whatever the resolution of your screen, is the total available screen size.

Comment: Yes the navigation bar takes up space on the screen making the actual space smaller than 1280x800. It gives my graphic black bars on each side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a screenshot of an ICS emulator running on 1280x800 pixels. The system bar is 48 pixels high, so 752 pixels remain for your application.

[image: 1280x800 tablet]

Comment: Just use Microsoft's Paint. It has a pixel indicator in de lower left corner.

Comment: The navigation bar is actually 48 pixels high, as Fluffy points out. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is interesting, according to [this](http://www.displaymate.com/Tablet_ShootOut_2.htm) the active resolution would be 1280x752 (Android 3.1) But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093194/supporting-all-android-tablets-resolutions) talks about something I support, design for any resolution.

I hope this helps out better. Good luck.

Comment: @Rocky you're right, besides that I should have put it in the comments in the first place as an indication. I might as well delete it ;)